# Reference for biography of Philipp Lenard

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, history

I was asked to write about the physicist [Philipp Lenard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philipp_Lenard), known for his research with cathode rays and as a winner of a Nobel prize, but i wasn't able to find good references (with exception for those in German). Where should i look in order to make a good research about his life?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a physicist rather than physics.